# QGIS 3 Edit Attribute Field Name

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, attribute-table

I want to change the name of an attibute field in QGIS 3. The duplicate referred to seems to require the plug in table manager which is no longer available. I have looked at properties and have spent much time trying to work out how to do this.

Comment: possible duplicated https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/312780/qgis-3-how-to-rename-attribute-field-names-for-geopackage-layer

Comment: what is your data source? If you were using a database, this is no problem. If you're using a shapefile, don't blame QGIS!

Comment: It’s a spatialite layer as source. I just want to change a field attribute name it seems really difficult to do. I’m QGIS newbie historical geographer so this is a steep learning curve. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

`Refactor fields` is no longer a plugin. Now it's a core feature. Access it through the Processing Toolbox (Processing menu > Toolbox).

[image]